Webnovel in which the main character is transferred to another world as the daughter of a Duke with two sons and magical powers
I already read the webnovel until a certain point, so the story will include points from later chapters.
The main character (MC) was from the real world and loved to read many books. Then she was transferred into the world of a book as (I think) a Duke's daughter. The daughter has pink hair, while the Duke and his two sons have black hair.
The story starts with the MC being mistreated my her uncle's family, until the MC's father collects her back after fighting on the frontline. The Duke and his sons have magic power, while the MC doesn't. That's why the Duke sent the MC far away to prevent his magic power from affecting the helpless MC's baby body. Now that the MC has grown to 6-7 years old, the Duke came to take the MC back.
The MC has a power with some restrictions (I don't recall what those restrictions were). She has a 'system' (a floating notification, I don't know how to describe it; imagine the Solo Leveling system, but the system kinda has an attitude, like the system from The Greatest Estate Developer) which allows her to obtain power from characters from other books she read before being transferred to this world.

Was the MC a person from the real world who was transmigrated into a book or game?

Yes, MC from the real world. MC loves to read many books when she's still in the real world. MC also got powers from 'system'(a floating notification, I don't know how to describe it, imagine Solo Levelling system, but the system kinda have an attitude, like the system fron The Greatest Estate Developer'). The system allows the MC to obtained power from other characters from other books that the MC have read

"MC also got powers from 'system'(a floating notification, I don't know how to describe it" I think I know what you mean. I call those "floating notifications" status screens, but I don't know how widely-used that term is in respect to webnovels, manhwa, etc.

@LogicDictates The term is just "System" to describe game-like popups in general. They typically assign/notify of game-like quests, or they may be self-aware (vaguely like in-game chat with either the system itself or with some god(s)).

@qazmlpok - Yeah, I'm aware that the word 'system' is commonly used in regard to that sort of video game-like mechanic as a whole. Obviously, we've both seen numerous questions posted here where the protagonist is described by the OP as getting some sort of 'system,' and I know exactly what that entails when I read those descriptions. But I call the 'floating notifications' on their own status screens, whereas I'd use the term system to refer to the whole shebang (i.e., the notifications, abilities and whatnot), rather than just the notifications on their own.

This is Lord Baby Runs a Romance Fantasy With Cash.

Romance fantasies were my happy little refuge. I’ve read countless novels and left tons of top comments in RF forums, and where did that lead me? To getting hit by a reincarnation truck! Now I’m stuck in a zero-star rated story fighting for my life! My father, the vile Duke Phaeraton, abandoned me. I’m barely surviving, no thanks to my thieving uncle, Marquess Tarenka. I’m not even the heroine of this novel! But what’s this? “QUEST COMPLETE. ABILITY ACTIVATED.” Is this my ticket out of here?


An avid reader of romance fantasy (RF) web novels is hit by a truck and killed. An angel acting as a messenger for a god named Apthanes appears before her ghost and offers her the chance to be reincarnated into a world created by that god based on RF novels. She accepts, with some conditions: she wants to be reborn with a silver spoon in her mouth, a handsome father and brother, and a special power like the heroines usually have in the thousands of novels she's read.
She then wakes up in that world as Luatisha Phaeraton, a four-year-old girl currently living with her uncle, Marquess Tarenka, and cousin, Clytié, while her father, Duke Phaeraton, is fighting at the front line of a war. Her uncle treats her like crap, making it clear that she's an unwanted burden and questioning whether she's really even the Duke's daughter, since she doesn't have magic like her father and brothers, and has pink hair like her mother rather than black hair like them. Then her father shows up out of the blue and takes her back to his home, where she receives much better treatment.
Soon after that, her special power called "Rush and Cash" activates, bringing up status screens only she can see. These screens inform her that she can earn cash by fulfilling certain requirements, and then use that cash to summon the RF novels she's read, and extract and use the powers of the heroines of those novels.



In chapter 19, her father explains to her that the reason he left her with her uncle and cousin rather than her brothers is because her brothers were emitting magic that would've killed her if she stayed with them while he was away. In chapter 26, she meets two of her older brothers, Ares and Ixion.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas. The web novel can be read at Novel Updates.

Yes...This is it. Thank you so much. I remembered that she's a Duke's daughter, so I tried searching Duke's daughter title. I have no idea how many Duke's daughter novel out there

@M.I.Athena - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
